# Challenging RTMP stream

Tags: firefox, download, streaming, sniffing, rtmp

I can't figure out how to download this RTMP stream. I got all the info here extracted from Firefox:

```
    netstreambasepath=http://streamin.to/embed-stx1jx4ysd5a-828x480.html
    id=vplayer
    file=85/1612548173_n.flv?h=3kipfvn55tuzcg3h5eksbdvhzmsxwlhpsbk7m2ab3ybz34efqrdxpbba7ozq
    streamer=rtmp://95.211.214.98:1935/vod?h=3kipfvn55tuzcg3h5eksbdvhzmsxwlhpsbk7m2ab3ybz34efqrdxpbba7ozq
    skin=http://streamin.to/player/skin.zip
    duration=6173
    controlbar.position=over
    volume=0
    mute=true
```

I'm trying to use rtmpsrv following:

[How can I download stream videos with rtmp protocol? From Harvard Extension, more specifically](https://superuser.com/questions/528818/how-can-i-download-stream-videos-with-rtmp-protocol-from-harvard-extension-mor)

I've tried :

```
rtmpdump.exe -r "rtmp://95.211.214.98:1935/" -y "85/1612548173_n.flv?h=3kipfvn55tuzcg3h5eksbdvhzmsxwlhpsbk7m2ab3ybz34efqrdxpbba7ozq"
RTMPDump v2.3
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
WARNING: You haven't specified an output file (-o filename), using stdout
Connecting ...
INFO: Connected...
ERROR: RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header
```

and

```
rtmpdump.exe -r "rtmp://95.211.214.98:1935/vod?h=3kipfvn55tuzcg3h5eksbdvhzmsxwlhpsbk7m2ab3ybz34efqrdxpbba7ozq"
RTMPDump v2.3
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
ERROR: You must specify a playpath (--playpath) or url (-r "rtmp://host[:port]/playpath") containing a playpath
```

and

```
rtmpdump.exe -t "rtmp://95.211.214.98:1935/vod?h=3kipfvn55tuzcg3h5eksbdvhzmsxwlhpsbk7m2ab3ybz34efqrdxpbba7ozq"
RTMPDump v2.3
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
ERROR: You must specify a hostname (--host) or url (-r "rtmp://host[:port]/playpath") containing a hostname
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:

```
rtmpdump.exe -r "rtmp://95.211.214.98:1935/vod?h=3kipfvn55tuzcg3h5eksbdvhzmsxwlhpsbk7m2ab3ybz34efqrdxpbba7ozq" -y "85/1612548173_n.flv?h=3kipfvn55tuzcg3h5eksbdvhzmsxwlhpsbk7m2ab3ybz34efqrdxpbba7ozq"
```